# CMake is unable to find gRPC libraries even though they're installed (mac)

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, homebrew, grpc

I'm trying to use the gRPC library however I keep getting an error telling me it can't find the .cmake file or I get a linker errors, presumably due to my CMakeLists.txt. In [examples I'm following](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/CMakeLists.txt) they refer to the library in cmake simply as gRPC, and I've also tried the keyword grpc_cpp_plugin, however neither seems to be working.

For context I'm using macOS Mojave and I've installed the gRPC library using homebrew.

Homebrew installed the gRPC library in `/usr/local/Cellar/grpc/1.22.0`.

I used a cmake file that works for another project here, however I've added on the protobuf and gRPC libraries, and after adding them is when I get the error. Again some of the code is borrowed from the link above (specifically the names for where the gRPC file should be).

My CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )
project( gRPC_server )

# setup opencv
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

# SETUP PROTOBUF
set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
find_package( Protobuf REQUIRED )
set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF protobuf::libprotobuf)

# SETUP GRPC
find_package( gRPC REQUIRED )
set(_GRPC_GRPCPP_UNSECURE gRPC::grpc++_unsecure)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})

# mostly just to set it to the correct compiler
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x -Wall -g -Werror")

add_executable( server server.cpp compiled/image.grpc.pb.cc compiled/image.pb.cc )
target_link_libraries( server ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${_GRPC_GRPCPP_UNSECURE} ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF} )

add_executable( client client.cpp compiled/image.grpc.pb.cc compiled/image.pb.cc )
target_link_libraries( client ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${_GRPC_GRPCPP_UNSECURE} ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF} )
```

What's particularly odd is that the error message makes no sense

```
-- Found OpenCV: /opt/local (found version "3.4.3") 
-- Found Protobuf: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a (found version "3.7.0") 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindgRPC.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "gRPC", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gRPC" with any of
  the following names:

    gRPCConfig.cmake
    grpc-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gRPC" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gRPC_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "gRPC"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

If I comment out the gRPC stuff I get a linker error.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: did you try adding the grpc install location to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`? (or the folder containing either gRPCConfig.cmake or grpc-config.cmake)

Comment: That's part of what I don't get. I've never had to create a gRPCConfig.cmake file before and I don't have one or know how to build one for gRPC. I also don't know what `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is however I googled it and it looks like it's just a keyword for the directory I'm building in, which I think it just referring back to the .cmake files.

Comment: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is a list of folders where cmake searches for libraries (in addition to the default system paths). when you call `find_package`, cmake will search for a FindXXX.cmake module. if there is none (grpc has no such module), cmake searches for a config file (XXX-config.cmake or XXXConfig.cmake) in system paths and `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. these config files are provided by the library, not by you. when you build and install grpc with cmake, the config file should be placed somewhere in the install folder (e.g. in lib/cmake/grpc/).

Comment: Potentially related: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/19873

Answer (score 5):

You have to find gRPC through pkg-config. It has been stated in the gRPC C++ [QuickStart](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/cpp/#install-grpc).

Example cmake codes:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GRPC REQUIRED grpc)
pkg_search_module(GRPCPP REQUIRED grpc++>=1.22.0)
```

I use those in my own [tensorflow-serving-client](https://github.com/figroc/tensorflow-serving-client) repo.

Comment: This is outdated - you can now use `find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)...
target_link_libraries(my_exe gRPC::grpc++)` (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/cpp#cmake)